# Automatically update files which inherit Template in Dreamweaver CS5?

Tags: html, templates, save, dreamweaver

I am frequently changing code in a Dreamweaver template, and every time I do so, the "Update Template Files" dialog box appears, followed by the "Update Pages" dialog box which I have to manually close. Is there any way to have my inheriting HTML documents automatically update, without having to deal with the 2 dialog boxes, every time I save the Template?

I am coming from developing ASP.NET in Visual Studio, which only requires a quick save, and a reload on the browser. This may seem like a petty problem, but the frequency of it is getting to me quickly...

Answer (score 0):

No, you must go through the Update Pages dialogs if you are using Dreamweaver Templates.  The only way to truly get rid of it is to switch out of Templates entirely and use some form of include call to handle the "templated" areas of your site.  Editing the called include file and saving it will update all pages that use that file.  Just like Templates without the slow dialogs and occasional bugs